# only constructors take member initializers

Tags: c++

I am trying to install a simulator. While trying to compile the source files, I am getting the error message in the title from the code below.

```
#include "core.hpp"
core::core(const pe_id &id, const uint64_t &t,
           shared_ptr<id_factory<packet_id> > pif,shared_ptr<tile_statistics> st, 
           logger &l, shared_ptr<random_gen> r, shared_ptr<memory> mem, 
           uint32_t number_of_core_msg_types, uint32_t msg_q_size, uint32_t 
           bytes_per_flit) throw(err) : pe(id), system_time(t), stats(st), log(l), ran(r),
           m_msg_queue_size(msg_q_size), m_bytes_per_flit(bytes_per_flit), 
           m_memory(mem), m_packet_id_factory(pif), 
           m_receive_channel_round_robin_pointer(0), m_send_queue_round_robin_pointer(0)
{ 
  m_number_of_msg_types = number_of_core_msg_types + mem->number_of_mem_msg_types();
  m_first_core_msg_type = mem->number_of_mem_msg_types();
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_number_of_msg_types; ++i) {
    m_in_msg_queues[i] = shared_ptr<messageQueue> (new messageQueue(i, m_msg_queue_size));
    m_out_msg_queues[i] = shared_ptr<messageQueue> (new messageQueue(i, m_msg_queue_size));
}
  m_memory->set_core_send_queues(m_out_msg_queues);
  m_memory->set_core_receive_queues(m_in_msg_queues);
}
```

I also attach the declaration of core class from header file. It seems that the core::core is constructor but still I got the above error.

```
class core : public pe {
public:
core (const pe_id &id, const uint64_t &system_time,
     shared_ptr<id_factory<packet_id> > packet_id_factory,
     shared_ptr<tile_statistics> stats, logger &log,
     shared_ptr<random_gen> ran,
     shared_ptr<memory> mem,
     uint32_t number_of_core_msg_types, uint32_t msg_queue_size, uint32_t m_bytes_per_flit) throw(err);
virtual ~core() throw();
```

Any help about it?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I would argue that excessive number of arguments to any function is a bad code/design smell.

Comment: At what line do you get the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your [***deprecated*** exception specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec). It should only be on the declaration and not the definition.